# Where to post bugs from openMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I found a bug in openMDAO. Nothing serious, but I couldn't find where to post the bug. Does someone know if there is a bug tracker or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMDAO uses github for its source code repository, and you can use their issue tracker by posting [here](https://github.com/openmdao/openmdao/issues)

Comment: Thanks Justin. I went there the first time and saw no issues so it lead me to believe that it was not in use...

Comment: The team uses a different system for our internal workflow, but we accept issues from outside via github issues.